# DefaultMessageListenerContainer, knowledge about the queue to listen on

Tags: java, spring, queue, jms, spring-jms

Is there any possibility to know inside the onMessage method, which queue the MessageListener is listening to?

**My Spring-config (a part of it):**

```
<bean id="abstractMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" abstract="true">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" parent="abstractMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destinationName" value="MY.QUEUE" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="myMessageListener" />
</bean>

<bean id="myMessageListener" class="my.package.structure.ListenerClass"></bean>
```

**My Listener Class:**

```
public class ListenerClass implements MessageListener {


    public void onMessage(Message msg) {

    //where do I know from, on which queue the message has been written to?

    }

}
```

Is there any out-of-the box solution? Or any custom solution to get the queue/destination-name?

Do need the queue in a subsequent batch-processing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. in trivial cases at least:

`msg.getJMSDestination()` will give you the destination as a javax.jms.Destination object. Typically `.toString()` returns something like: `queue://MYQUEUENAME`

However, in some JMS implementations, there might be multihop queues, such as a static pub/sub setup in WebSphere MQ where you might write your message to one queue and it will bounce around a route to end up in a completly different queue. Also, you might have the case of an ESB with logic in the middle that routes the message. In such cases, you will need to think twice before relying to much on the JMSDestination attribute. Otherwise, go ahead.

Comment: @Petter : What If I needed the whole *DefaultMessageListenerContainer* instance ?
Here's a link to my situation if you may http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207792/not-able-to-stop-mqueue-listener