# Not able to Stop MQueue listener

Tags: spring, message-queue, lifecycle, spring-jms

I have the following configuration for my MQueue:

```
<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="cachedConnectionFactory" acknowledge="auto">
    <jms:listener id="myListenerId" destination="myDestination" ref="myListener" method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

When I try to stop the reception of JMS messages, I write the following code

```
jmsManagement = myProject.instance.getContext().getBean('myListenerId',Lifecycle.class);
jmsManagement.stop();
```

PS :

- When I `stop()` my listener, the `isRunning()` return False, but I still get messages through the MQueue... the `onMessage` gets triggered.
- `jmsManagement` is an instance of the class `Lifecycle`. Even when I changed it to `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, same thing.
- I'm receiving messages before calling `start()`, even when `autoStartup` is set to false.
- `jmsManagement.shutdown();` didn't stop the listener from being triggered.

Does anyone have an idea about how to stop this MQ listener ?
Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: what is the cache level of the cachedConnectionFactory ? he must be >= 1

Comment: @HassenBennour 
It actually equals 3 
`<property name="sessionCacheSize" value="3" />`

Comment: sorry i meant DefaultMessageListenerContainer.cacheLevel, try to call DefaultMessageListenerContainer.shutdown() to stop Connection & Shut down the listeners

Comment: @HassenBennour 

cacheLevel is equal to 3.

`jmsManagement.shutdown();` didn't stop the listener from being triggered...
I couldn't find a logic conclusion

Comment: me too, and i do not understand how do you do that myProject.instance.getContext().getBean('myListenerId',DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class); without exception because myListenerId is a listener

Comment: @HassenBennour `myListenerId` is an instance of `Defau‌​ltMessageListenerCon‌​tainer` because declared `<jms:listener-container container-type="**default**"`... So it's not supposed generate an exception.
PS: Please check my answer below? I solved the problem by forcing `autoStartup` to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to set `autoStartup` to *true*.

Since I can't do that using `jms:listener-container`, I instanciated a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` bean and set the `autoStartup` property to *false*.

Here's the code that worked for me :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"  id="pitagorCPYListener">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listenerPitagorCPY" />
</bean>

 <bean id="defaultDestination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="#{mqConnectionFactory.destination}"/>
  </bean>
```