# MQ messages discarded following a regular pattern

Tags: spring, message-queue, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I'm using [HemrèsJMS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/) to test my MQueue, and everytime I send a message, I have **exactly 2 out of three MQ messages that are lost**.

I have the following configuration :

```
<bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.integrator.init.MqConnectionFactory" init-method="init"
 scope="singleton">
    <property name="environnement" ref="env" />   
    <property name="destination" value=""/>     
</bean>

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="3" />
</bean>

<bean id="listenerPitagorCPY" class="com.integrator.pitagor.cpy.messaging.listenerPitagorCPY">
    <property name="pitagorCPYDelegate" ref="pitagorCPYDelegate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pitagorCPYListener"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="listenerPitagorCPY" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="4" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultDestination" scope="singleton" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="#{mqConnectionFactory.destination}" />
</bean>
```

The following listener is triggered exactly once every three sent messages :

```
public class listenerPitagorCPY implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
       // some work
  }
}
```

**Edit :**

The regular pattern is : "*Nok, Nok, **OK**, Nok, Nok, **OK**, Nok, Nok, **OK***" ...

When I add `<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="3" />`, the pattern become "*Nok, Nok, **OK, OK, OK**, Nok, Nok, **OK, OK, OK**, Nok, Nok, **OK, OK, OK***" ...

Any idea about "why" such reception pattern exist ?

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason why 'autoStartup' is false? Can you try with a 'true' value?

Comment: @kmansoor I had to set it to False because I manually start and stop the MQueue (from the app's IHM).. Check this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207792/not-able-to-stop-mqueue-listener

Comment: Can you say with certainty there isn't any other listener on the queue?

Comment: Yes, and if there was another listener, it wouldn't have such a regulated consumption pattern. Furthermore, as I described in the "Edit" section of my question, the `concurrentConsumers` have also an impact on this pattern

Comment: Every time you send 1 message you lose another two messages? Where are these other messages coming from? Could you show the code that puts the messages and the code that gets the messages?

Comment: @MoragHughson I'm using Hermès client to send messages. 
The regular pattern is : _Nok, Nok, OK, Nok, Nok, OK, Nok, Nok, OK_ ...

When I change the `concurrentConsumers` to 3, the pattern become _Nok, Nok, OK, OK, OK, Nok, Nok, OK, OK, OK, Nok, Nok, OK, OK, OK_ ...

Comment: Could you update your question to be more explicit about these messages you are sending. You answer hints at something that I don't yet understand, but that I feel is important to understanding your question. Are you using Pub/Sub for example? Is that why when you send 1 message you have 3 messages in the environment?

Comment: And also, as requested a moment earlier - could you show your code (or snippets of it) as we really have no idea what your application is doing to be able to comment on why it isn't working for you.

Comment: I just updated my question by adding more code and more details about this behaviour.
And to correct your understanding, I don't "receive 3 messages every 1 sent", "I receive 1 message every 3 sent"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140175/discussion-between-radhwen-and-morag-hughson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As evident as it may seem, there was another client listening to my MQueue.